# Trouble Installing ros-humble-turtle Packages in my Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy Jellyfish Virtual Machine on a Macbook Pro M1 Computer

Tags: ros2, ubuntu, turtlebot3, ros-humble, nav2

I'm currently trying to learn ROS2 and NAV2 on a Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy Jellyfish Virtual Machine on UTM in my Macbook Pro M1 laptop. So far, with ROS2 Humble Hawksbill, I've been able to install the following packages with these commands:

```
sudo apt install ros-humble-navigation2
sudo apt install ros-humble-nav2-bringup
sudo apt install ros-humble-turtlebot3*
```

However, when I try to install the ros-humble-turtle packages with this command, I'm returned the error below the given command I used:

`sudo apt install ros-humble-turtle*`

```
Setting up ros-humble-turtlebot4-setup (1.0.2-1jammy.20230807.153410) ...
Failed to restart chrony.service: Unit chrony.service not found.
dpkg: error processing package ros-humble-turtlebot4-setup (--configure):
 installed ros-humble-turtlebot4-setup package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 5
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ros-humble-turtlebot4-setup
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
ruloco967@ubuntu:~$
```

Does anyone have any idea of how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. First install `chrony`

```bash
sudo apt install chrony
```

2. Then try the ROS packages installation again